# java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com/sun/mail/util/MailLogger while trying to send e-mail from JAX-WS

Tags: java, eclipse, web-services, email

I'm sending a GET request in API (based on JAX-WS, currently runs on the tomcat server of the Eclipse), which should send an e-mail using Gmail.
I'm getting the following exception:

> org.glassfish.jersey.server.ContainerException: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com/sun/mail/util/MailLogger

What did I do?

1. Added the javax.mail dependency into the pom.xml

   ```
   <dependency>
       <groupId>com.sun.mail</groupId>
       <artifactId>javax.mail</artifactId>
       <version>1.6.0</version>
       <scope>test</scope>
   </dependency>
   ```
2. Added javax.mail-1.6.0.jar to build path
3. Copied javax.mail-1.6.0.jar to `C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_144\jre\lib\ext`

None of the above fixed the issue,
Please advise, 
Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Fixed by coping javax.mail-1.6.0.jar to C:\Program Files\Java\jre1.8.0_144\lib\ext

Answer (score 1):

According to [mvnrepository.com](https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.sun.mail/javax.mail/1.6.0) all you need is this

```
<dependency>
<groupId>com.sun.mail</groupId>
<artifactId>javax.mail</artifactId>
<version>1.6.0</version>
</dependency>
```

to add on your pom.xml

Also after making changes to your pom.xml right click on your project and run a maven clean, maven install and maven update project.

Comment: I cannot start tomcat after removing the scope section- SEVERE: A child container failed during start
java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException: org.apache.catalina.LifecycleException: Failed to start component [StandardEngine[Catalina].StandardHost[localhost].StandardContext[/API]]

Comment: please provide the pom.xml file and the full error you get on your console

Answer (score 0):

In your `pom.xml` file **remove the line `<scope>test</scope>`**.